# Integral $\int_My\sin(xy)d(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can one find out the value of this integral?

$$\int_My\sin(xy)d(x,y)$$

with $M := \{(x,y)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x \leq \pi,0 \leq y \leq 1\}$

Looking just at $y\sin(xy)$, it becomes $-\cos(yx)+C$, but I don't know how to appraoch an integral with a lower bound that looks like the one given above.

Comment: $\int_M$ just means you're integrating over the rectangle $M$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see more clearly what is happening, you need to understand that you can rewrite this integral as
$$\int_0^1\int_0^\pi y\sin(xy)dx dy.$$
We will first calculate the inside integral for a fixed $y\in [0,1]$.
$$\int_0^\pi y\sin(xy)dx = \left[y\frac{1}{y} (-\cos(xy))\right]_0^\pi = 1-\cos(\pi y)$$
Then, you only have to compute the integral with regard to $y$, that is
$$\int_M y\sin(xy)d(x,y) = \int_0^1 1-\cos(\pi y)dy = \left[y-\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi y)\right]_0^1 = 1$$